# Context free grammar $\{0^n 1^m : n,m \geq 0\}$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I just started studying the concept of context-free grammars and I find something very confusing. Watching a video I found someone tackling the problem ${0^n 1^m : n,m\geq 0}$.

I thought that the simple answer would have the production rules:
$S \rightarrow \epsilon \ | \ 0S \ | \ S1$

Since I thought this implies that whichever string you have, you can always place a $0$ in front of the string or a $1$ at the end of the string. However it seems that you can also create the string $0101$ with these production rules, could someone explain to me why my production rules won't give the desired outcome?

Comment: How exactly do you produce 0101? Show me.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's the problem, I don't exactly get it but this is what I found on the internet. S -> 0S -> 0S1 -> 01S1 -> 010S1 -> 0101. What's bugging me is the step from 0S1 to 01S1, since there is no step from S to 1S

Comment: The longer I think about it, the more the derivation to 0101 seems incorrect. Could my answer be correct?

Comment: Looks like you asked ChatGPT. That step is absolute nonsense. There _is_ no way to get to 0101. Yes, your answer was correct.

Comment: @gnasher729 it's weird that in the youtube video from "Easy Theory" he uses a different approach which is overcomplicating the problem. He solves it with:
S -> 0S | P

P -> 1P | \epsilon. But thanks!

Comment: I fixed your notation, however I suggest you to read this so that you can learn how to write mathematical notation on this website: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't produce $0101$ because every time you use $0S$ you are putting a $0$ at the beginning of the string. Whenever you want to insert a $1$, it directly goes to the end of the string and it will remain the last element of the string. This holds also in the opposite way. You can add $1$s and, if you add a $0$, it became the first element of the string and you can only add characters to the right of this $0$.

The proposed production rules are correct and it can be easily shown by induction on the number of times a production rule is applied $ \ell$.

The strings obtained by the production rules (starting from empty string) $S\rightarrow \epsilon \ | \ 0S \ | \ S1 $ are in the form $0^n1^m$.

a) Base case: $\ell=0$ this is true because $S=\epsilon = 0^0 1^0$.

b) Inductive step: Assuming the thesis true for $\ell$ applications of the production rules, we show it for $\ell +1$ applications. Assume $S$ is the results of $\ell$ applications of the production rules, thus, by inductive hypothesis $S=0^n1^m$. Now, we have three possibilities, one for each production rule:

1. $S\rightarrow \epsilon$, in this case the thesis remains true.
2. $S\rightarrow 0S$, then we added a starting $0$, so if by inductive hypotesis $S=0^n1^m$, we obtained $0^{n+1}1^m$.
3. $S\rightarrow S1$, as previous case, we obtain $0^n 1^{m+1}$.